# Continue Counting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I stop the *NoAnsweredQuestion.Count* when I click on a button...

**Problem:**
When I click on the reset button, the `NoAnsweredQuestion.Count` is still counting go to the maximum limit

Random:

```
private void SetcurrentQuestion()
{
    int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, NoAnsweredQuestion.Count);
    currentQuestion = NoAnsweredQuestion[randomQuestionIndex];

    factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;
    correctAnswerText.text = currentQuestion.answered;
}
```

***This is my limit:***

```
public void ContinueTransition()
{
    if (NoAnsweredQuestion.Count == 10)
    {
        FinalScore.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(TransitiontoNextQuestion());
        updatequestion();
    }
}
```

*Reset button:*

```
public void Restart()
{
   var form = new WWWForm();
   var www  = new WWW(restartBegGrammarIAQ, form);

   SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
   Time.timeScale = 1f;
   GameIsPaused   = false;
}
```

Comment: `NoAnsweredQuestion.Clear()` in your restart method

Comment: Miss Nathalia Soragge ..Thank for you Answer :) its work

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge I encourage you to flesh out your comment into a full answer, and post it below. This way, the OP can accept your answer and the question can be marked as successfully resolved. (And you both get rep too on answer acceptance, which is nice for unlocking more privileges here.)

Answer (score 1):

Add `NoAnsweredQuestion.Clear()` in your restart method and it should work